# Is it possible to create different stepsize for different yAxis intervals on chartJs?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a chart like below

[image]

as you can see starts from 0 and `stepSize` is 0.1 but instead of this I want it start from `0` again and print `0.7` directly then keep going on each `0.1` steps. Here you can see the expected below

[image]

This is the configuration that I made for `ticks` on `yAxis`

```
ticks: {
  min: 0,
  // forces step size to be 5 units
  stepSize: 0.1
}
```

I need something like `stepSize:0.7`(between 0-0.7) then `0.1` if bigger than `0.7`.Unfortunately I don't have a chance to implement like this. Is there any alternative to this?

Codepen Demo : https://codepen.io/Cicek96/pen/vYGVwmy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could fake the tick of the zero line by defining `ticks` as follows:

```
ticks: {
  min: 0.65,
  stepSize: 0.1,
  callback: (value, index, values) => index + 1 == values.length ? 0 : value
}
```

> For further explanations, have a look at [Creating Custom Tick Formats](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/labelling.html#creating-custom-tick-formats) from Chart.js documentation.

Please take a look at the following runnable code and see how it works.

```js
new Chart(document.getElementById("myChart"), {
    type: "line",
    data: {
        labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
        datasets: [{
            label: "APAC RE index",
            data: [0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7],
            fill: false,
            borderColor: "rgb(255, 0, 0)"
        }]
    },
    options: {
      legend: {
        display: false
      },
      scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            min: 0.65,
            stepSize: 0.1,
            callback: (value, index, values) => index + 1 == values.length ? 0 : value
          }
        }]
      }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="90"></canvas>
```